# Textbox Below Size Attribute in product page

Tags: magento2.3, product-page

i want to add textbox names like notes under size in products page.

Could you please any one tell me how to do. i have tried to via attribute but it doesn't help me.
[image]

Comment: pls provide more info....why you need textbox here?

Comment: i want to allow option for enter some text from user for gift message

Comment: Guide me if I'm wrong. My idea is...you need to create additional column in quote_item table and sales_order_item table, after addtocart you need to save it in quote_item and after placed order you need to move it to sales_order_item from quote_item. And display it in admin order item section..Pls let me know if you need any code examples.

Comment: yes give me some samples. because i m new to this magento.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Module for this question

**STEP1:** Create a module using required files as

app/code/Vendor/Test/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Vendor_Test',
   __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Vendor/Test/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Test" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

**STEP2:** Create text box under qty text box in 
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Your gift message custom field here -->
        <input type="text"
           name="gift_message"
           id="gift_message"
           value=""
           title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Gift messages') ?>"
           class="input-text"
                       />
        <!-- Your gift message custom field here -->

        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

**STEP3:** Create `gift_message` column in `quote_item` and `sales_order_item` tables using setup files

app/code/Vendor/Test/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Test\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $connection->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('quote_item'),
                'gift_message',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => '',
                    'comment' => 'Gift Message'
                ]
            );
            $connection->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('sales_order_item'),
                'gift_message',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => '',
                    'comment' => 'Gift Message'
                ]
            );
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

**STEP4:** Create an event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` to save custom field value on addtocart 
app/code/Vendor/Test/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="save_gift_message_to_cart" instance="Vendor\Test\Observer\AddProductAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Test/Observer/AddProductAfterObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Test\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddProductAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $giftMessages = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParam('gift_message');
        if(!empty($giftMessages)){
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
            $item = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);
            $item->setGiftMessage($giftMessages);
            $item->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**STEP5:** Create a plugin for move quote table gift_message data to sales_order_item table column

app/code/Vendor/Test/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="quote_item_to_order_item" type="Vendor\Test\Plugin\QuoteToOrderItem"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Test/Plugin/QuoteToOrderItem.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Test\Plugin;

class QuoteToOrderItem
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
     * @param array $additional
     *
     * @return object $orderItem
     */
    public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []
    ) {
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);
        $orderItem->setGiftMessage($item->getGiftMessage());
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

**STEP6:** Display the custom gift_messge field value in adminpanel->sales->orders->specific order->orderitems

app/code/Vendor/Test/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="gift_message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gift message</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="gift_message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-giftmessage</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn"
                   name="column_gift_message"
                   template="Vendor_Test::gift_message.phtml" group="column" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Test/view/adminhtml/templates/gift_message.phtml

```
<?php
$_item = $block->getItem();
$giftMessage = $_item->getGiftMessage();

if( !empty($giftMessage) ) {
    echo $_item->getGiftMessage();
}
```